# Algolia: Change label of currentRefinements item

Tags: javascript, algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch

I'm using a `toggleRefinement` widget to check if an item is on sale.
There is an extra attribute in my index called `on_sale`. It has `true` or `false` value.

As a result my `currentRefinements` widget shows `true` or `false` instead of a better text like "Only on sale".

Is there a way to change the output?

Unlike other widgets, there is no `template` attribute for this one. [See docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/current-refinements/js/)

This is my current code:

```
instantsearch.widgets.toggleRefinement({
  container: '#onsale',
  attribute: 'on_sale',
  templates: {
    labelText: 'Only on sale',
  },
}),
```

This is my current output:

```
<ul class="ais-CurrentRefinements-list">
    <li class="ais-CurrentRefinements-item">
        <span class="ais-CurrentRefinements-label">On_sale:</span>
        <span class="ais-CurrentRefinements-category">
            <span class="ais-CurrentRefinements-categoryLabel">true</span>
            <button class="ais-CurrentRefinements-delete">✕</button>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Provide the function that generates true or false and adds to `toggleRefinement`

Comment: There is no function, the `true` and `false` are values in the Algolia index

Comment: You said `It outputs`. 'Outputs' is more related to functions. I suggested an edit

Comment: ah okay, sorry for the misleading wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template option doesn't exist but you have the possibility to control the output of the widget with the connector API ([doc](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/current-refinements/js/#connector)). You can render the widget with whatever output. You have complete control over it.

Comment: Okay, I will try to figure out a solution :-)